# バッチファイルのシンボリックリンクをExplorerから実行する際にカレントディレクトリをシンボリックリンクのあるディレクトリにする方法

Tags: windows, batch-file

```
@echo off
cd /d %~dp0
cd
pause
```

このようなバッチファイルを作成し、このファイルを指すシンボリックリンクを別のフォルダに作成しました。
コマンドプロンプト上でシンボリックリンクを実行すると期待通りシンボリックリンクのあるディレクトリに移動してそのパスが表示されるのですが、Explorer上でダブルクリックして実行すると実ファイルのあるディレクトリに移動してしまいます。
２行目の`cd /d %~dp0`はバッチファイルのあるディレクトリに移動するために（ググッて）書いた物ですが、ファイルがシンボリックリンクの時はシンボリックリンクのあるディレクトリに移動してほしいです。
どうすればExplorerから実行した時もシンボリックリンクのあるディレクトリに移動してくれるでしょうか？

Comment: ハードリンクではだめでしょうか？

Comment: あ、確かにハードリンクの方が良さそうですね。そうすることにします、ありがとうございます。なんとなく、パスと実体が一対一対応してないのが個人的に気持ち悪いですが……。

Comment: でもハードリンクではリンクと実ファイルのドライブが異なる場合に対応できないので質問はオープンのままにしておきます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

explorerはsymbolic linkの実体を起動しているようです。 なのでバッチファイル内で解決する方法は無さそうです。

```
[TOF c:\temp\original.cmd] 
echo off 
echo %CMDCMDLINE% 
pause 
[EOF] 

mklink c:\test\symlink.cmd c:\temp\original.cmd 
explorer c:\test\symlink.cmd 

C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /c ""c:\temp\original.cmd" " 
続行するには何かキーを押してください . . .
```

もう一段batchファイルをかますとかトリッキーな事をやると何とかなるかもしれませんが綺麗じゃないですねぇ

Comment: ありがとうございます。ふと思い立ち、質問文のバッチファイルを指すシンボリックリンクをさらに指すシンボリックリンクを作成してみたところ、その２段階目のシンボリックリンクはダブルクリックすると１段階目のシンボリックリンクのあるディレクトリを表示しました。仰るとおりだいぶ汚いですが……。

Answer (score 0):

ショートカットファイルのプロパティから設定できる「作業フォルダー」がそのような用途で使用されているのを見かけることがありますが、今回の状況で使用可能でしょうか？

`%cd%`で取得することができます(参考: [What is the current directory in a batch file? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4420078/4506703))。

手元のWindows7Pro(x64)及びWindows10Pro(x64)では、この「作業フォルダー」欄を空にすると、`%cd%`はファイルを置いているディレクトリを指しているようです…が、これが想定された挙動なのかは調べきれませんでした。

WindowsXPではまた異なった挙動になるようです。
参考: [作業フォルダの指定がないとショートカットが既定の作業フォルダから起動する](https://support.microsoft.com/ja-jp/kb/283065)

Comment: プロパティの「作業フォルダー」ですが、こちらの環境（Win10Pro 64bit）ではシンボリックリンクの場合空のままグレーアウトして編集することができません。その状態で質問のような挙動をします。

Comment: すみません、シンボリックリンク=ショートカットファイル、と読み替えてしまっていました。私の回答文はショートカットファイルについてのもので、質問であるシンボリックリンクに対するものではありませんでした。

Answer (score 0):

%0 に格納された値がエクスプローラーで実行した場合とコマンドプロンプトから実行した場合とで異なるようですが、実行直後はどちらも実行した場所のフォルダを示しているようです(win8.1 と win10 で確認)。

@echo on で実行すると挙動が観察できると思います。

c:\test1\test.bat(実体)
　→ 実行直後は c:\test1
c:\test2\test.bat(シンボリックリンク)
　→ 実行直後は c:\test2

このため、基本的に移動する必要はないのですが、例えば、カレントディレクトリのパスを処理中に使用したいなどでしたら、以下のような方法ではどうでしょうか。

・カレントディレクトリのパスを処理中に使えるよう変数に格納しておく

```
@echo off
set exeDir=%cd%
cd /d %exeDir%
cd
pause
```

単純に、すべて処理が完了したらカレントディレクトリに戻りたいなどの場合は

```
@echo off
pushd (移動先のパス)
～処理～
popd
pause
```

とすることで、最終的にカレントディレクトリに帰ってくることができます。

Comment: 「実行直後はどちらも実行した場所のフォルダを示している」というよりはシンボリックリンクを起動すると`%~dp0`の値と実際のカレントディレクトリが違うようになるということではないでしょうか？　この場合コマンドプロンプトで`C:\Users\user`などから`C:\test2\test.bat`を実行してしまうと`C:\Users\user`に移動する処理になってしまうと思います……。

Comment: はい、%0 (実行したファイルのパス)を使用した場合はそのようになります。

Comment: (途中で投稿してしまいました)そのため、%0 (%~dp0) を使用しない方法で

Comment: と思ったのですが、%~dp0 の使用は必須という事でしょうか。その場合は別の方が示されている通りもう一つのバッチファイルから呼び出すしかないと思います。

Comment: いえ、添付されたソースでそうなります。 `C:\User\user`から実行すると`%cd%`が`C:\User\user`になるので。

Comment: あ、すみません読み間違えていました。 `c:\user\user > c:\test\test.bat` をすると `%cd%` が `c:\user\user` ということですね。確かにこういう使い方だとこのやり方はだめですね…。